# Flutter API test is failing because of the asynchronous error

Tags: flutter, http, asynchronous, testing

I'm trying to implement my `AuthenticationRemoteDataSource` and I'm writing tests as I'm going. Like a test driven development.

This implementation is the latest layer communicating with API. I have two usecases: "createUser" and "getUsers". I have written tests for `createUser` and they're passing. Both in success and unsuccess states.
I have passed getUsers' successful state too but I can't find the error in the unsuccess test and it fails.

Here is my `getUsers` implementation inside the `AuthenticationRemoteDataSourceImplementation` class:

```
Future<List<UserModel>> getUsers() async {
    try {
      final response =
          await _client.get(Uri.parse('$kBaseUrl$kGetUsersEndpoint'));

      if (response.statusCode != 200) {
        throw (
          APIException(
            message: response.body,
            statusCode: response.statusCode,
          ),
        );
      }

      return List<DataMap>.from(jsonDecode(response.body) as List)
          .map((userdata) => UserModel.fromMap(userdata))
          .toList();
    } on APIException {
      rethrow;
    } catch (e) {
      throw APIException(message: e.toString(), statusCode: 505);
    }
  }
```

`DataMap` is basically `Map<String, dynamic>`.
`_client` is an instance of `http.Client` and it's the dependency of the implementation class.
`APIException` is a basic exception that contains a message and a status code.

And, here is my `getUsers` tests from the test file:

```
group('getUsers', () {
    const testList = [UserModel.empty()];
    test('Should return a [List<UserModel>] when the status code is 200',
        () async {
      // stubbing
      when(
        () => client.get(
          any(),
        ),
      ).thenAnswer((_) async =>
          http.Response(jsonEncode([testList.first.toMap()]), 200));

      // act
      final result = await remoteDataSource.getUsers();

      // assert
      expect(result, equals(testList));

      verify(() => client.get(Uri.parse('$kBaseUrl$kGetUsersEndpoint')))
          .called(1);
      verifyNoMoreInteractions(client);
    });

    // THIS IS THE FAILING TEST
    test('Should throw an [APIException] when the status code is not 200',
        () async {
      // stubbing
      when(() => client.get(any())).thenAnswer(
        (_) async => http.Response(
          'Server is down',
          505,
        ),
      );

      // act
      final methodCall = remoteDataSource.getUsers;

      // assert
      expect(
        () => methodCall(),
        throwsA(
          const APIException(
            message: 'Server is down',
            statusCode: 505,
          ),
        ),
      );

      verify(
        () => client.get(
          Uri.parse('$kBaseUrl$kGetUsersEndpoint'),
        ),
      ).called(1);

      verifyNoMoreInteractions(client);
    });
  });
```

The error I get:

```
Expected: throws APIException:<APIException(Server is down, 505)>
  Actual: <Closure: () => Future<List<UserModel>>>
   Which: threw APIException:<APIException((APIException(Server is down, 505)), 505)>
          stack package:cleanarchtdd/src/authentication/data/datasources/authentication_remote_data_source.dart 78:7  AuthenticationRemoteDataSourceImplementation.getUsers
                ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
                package:matcher                                                                                       expect
                package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart 454:18                                                    expect
                test\src\authentication\data\datasources\authentication_remote_data_source_test.dart 147:7            main.<fn>.<fn>

package:matcher                                                                             expect
package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart 454:18                                          expect
test\src\authentication\data\datasources\authentication_remote_data_source_test.dart 147:7  main.<fn>.<fn>
```

I have tried using the async keywords inside the both when and verify methods but they caused different errors. I wrote to test similar to `createUser` unsuccess state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug. I wrote `throw( APIException() )` in the implementation. I should've written, `throw APIException()`. Without the brackets obviously.